# Why won't this Schema validate this XML file?

Tags: validation, xsd

The XML file:

```
<Lista count="3">
  <Pelicula nombre="Jurasic Park 3">
    <Genero>Drama</Genero>
    <Director sexo="M">Esteven Spielberg</Director>
    <Temporada>
       <Anho>2002</Anho>
       <Semestre>Verano</Semestre>
    </Temporada>
  </Pelicula>
  <Pelicula nombre="Maldiciones">
    <Genero>Ficcion</Genero>
    <Director sexo="M">Pedro Almodovar</Director>
    <Temporada>
       <Anho>2002</Anho>
       <Semestre>Verano</Semestre>
    </Temporada>
  </Pelicula>
  <Pelicula nombre="Amor en New York">
    <Genero>Romance</Genero>
    <Director sexo="F">Katia Hertz</Director>
    <Temporada>
       <Anho>2002</Anho>
       <Semestre>Verano</Semestre>
    </Temporada>
  </Pelicula>
</Lista>
```

And here's the XML Schema file I made, it's not working. :\

```
<xsd:complexType name="Lista">
  <xsd:attribute name="count" type="xsd:integer" />
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:element name="Pelicula" type="xsd:string">
      <xsd:attribute name="nombre" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Genero" type="generoType"/>
          <xsd:element name="Director" type="directorType">
            <xsd:attribute name="sexo" type="sexoType"/>
          </xsd:element>
          </xsd:element name="Temporada">
           <xsd:complexType>
             <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="Anho" type="anhoType" />
               <xsd:element name="Semestre" type="semestreType" />
             </xsd:sequence>
           </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:element></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="sexoType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="F"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="M"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="directorType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="generoType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="Drama"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="Accion"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="Romance"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="Ficcion"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="semestreType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="Verano"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="Invierno"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="anhoType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
    <xsd:minInclusive value="1970"/>
    <xsd:maxInclusive value="2020"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring and using your types separately. This makes the XSD a bit longer, but less nested and more readable (and more reusable, too):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- document element -->
  <xs:element name="Lista" type="listaType" />

  <!-- type definitions -->
  <xs:complexType name="listaType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Pelicula" type="peliculaType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="count" type="countType" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="peliculaType">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="Genero" type="generoType" />
      <xs:element name="Director" type="directorType" />
      <xs:element name="Temporada" type="temporadaType" />
    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="nombre" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="directorType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="sexo" type="sexoType" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent> 
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="temporadaType">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="Anho" type="anhoType" />
      <xs:element name="Semestre" type="semestreType" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="sexoType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
      <xs:enumeration value="F" /> 
      <xs:enumeration value="M" /> 
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="generoType"> 
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
      <xs:enumeration value="Drama" /> 
      <xs:enumeration value="Accion" /> 
      <xs:enumeration value="Romance" /> 
      <xs:enumeration value="Ficcion" /> 
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="semestreType"> 
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
      <xs:enumeration value="Verano" /> 
      <xs:enumeration value="Invierno" /> 
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="anhoType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"> 
      <xs:minInclusive value="1970" /> 
      <xs:maxInclusive value="2020" /> 
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="countType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

The above validates your input XML.

Note that:

- The convention for the XML Schema namespace prefix is `xs` (AFAIK - you can still go on and use `xsd` if you prefer).
- The `count` attribute is really unnecessary, since the count can a) easily be calculated and b) there is a risk of something going wrong when the `count` attribute value and the actual count differ for some reason. Things that are derivable from the data should never be part of the data.

Oh, and to answer your initial question (why does mine not work):

- You never declare an actual document element ("Lista"), you just declare its type. Compare with my solution.
- In the `complexType name="Lista"`:

  - `attribute` cannot be the first child of a complex type. Attributes must be declared *after* everything else.
  - `complexContent` cannot contain `element`.
  - in fact, you don't need a `complexContent` at all - just use a `sequence` instead.
- In `element name="Pelicula"`:

  - The `type` attribute is illegal when you declare a `complexType` within.
- In the `complexType` for `"Pelicula"`:

  - Again, attributes last.
  - Don't use a `sequence` unless you want to make any other order of children illegal. In this type of document I would guess child order is irrelevant.
- In `element name="Director"`:

  - You can't declare any attributes since when you already declared a `type`. Include the `sexo` attribute in the `directorType`
- In `simpleType name="directorType"`:

  - This should in reality be a `complexType` containing `simpleContent` with an `extension`. This way you can include the `sexo` attribute
- Your XSD isn't even well formed XML.
- Your XML <strike>is</strike>was not well-formed, either. I have fixed it to be able to test in the first place.

P.S.: There is enough XSD documentation freely available to fix many of the basic problems you've had. There are XSD validators on the Net that help you by telling you what constructs are illegal. Knowing *everything* is absolutely not necessary, but a little reading + trial and error would have helped. ;-)

Comment: @Sergio: You are welcome. ;-) P.S.: I hope you didn't take the critique too personally. Thinking about it, I'm going to remove it. I guess I've made my point. ;-)

Comment: No please don't. One only learns from people who are better than you. I can only hope that everyone that answers my questions critique me like you have.

Answer (score 0):

For a start:

```
         <Semestre>Verano<Semestre>
```

...doesn't look well-formed.

Comment: @fd: I've just fixed the input in what was hopefully the intent of the OP.

Comment: Yes, I was a bit rushed, but spotted that error which could be easy to miss.  Just trying to get the ball rolling.  Your answer is excellent. +1